# Codename One - addActionListener of a Picker

Tags: codenameone

The following code, in a lot of version of Android and iOS, shows the options "Cancel" and "OK". I would like that the addActionListener code is executed only when the user taps on the "OK" button. At the moment, that code is executed even if the user taps the "Cancel" button:

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
    Picker languagePicker = new Picker();
    languagePicker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
    languagePicker.setStrings("Italian", "English", "German");
    languagePicker.setSelectedString("English");
    languagePicker.addActionListener((ev) -> {
        String newLanguage = languagePicker.getSelectedString();
        if (newLanguage != null && newLanguage.length() > 0) {
            Log.p("Language selected: " + newLanguage);
        }
    });
    hi.add(languagePicker);
    hi.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Picker` is a native component. As a result we just don't have that level of access or consistency when working with it. Keep in mind that in some forms it won't even have a list of elements so our control is very limited.

Answer (score 1):

I use the picker on several Android devices and they work as expected, meaning the action is performed only when the OK-Button is pressed.

Pressing the Cancel-Button does not incur in any action.

I could reproduce the error in the simulator, though.

Have you tried it on a device?

Comment: Yes, I confirm this behavior on real devices. Please note that the previous code should work and be tested in all Codename One supported devices, not only Android. Are you using Codename One?

Comment: Yes, I am using CN1 .... I have built a calendar app that uses the picker extensively. Maybe the are differences among devices ...

Comment: It's strange that I have this problem and you don't have it. I hope that Shai Almog can write some clarification... and maybe a solution :)

Comment: Is that a question? Which type of device. The picker implementation varies widely based on device/OS version. I suggest filing questions not answers as I don't see them otherwise.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't enough clear. I've just written a new (more clear?) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733763/codename-one-correct-use-of-the-picker