# Codename One - Correct use of the Picker

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to do a clear question about the use of the Picker, because my previous one in not enough clear: [Codename One - addActionListener of a Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48758348/codename-one-addactionlistener-of-a-picker/49692759)

The purpose of the Picker is to select one element from a set, such as a string of a set of strings, is it right? So, I want to give the user the opportunity to select a string from a set of strings, each of one corresponds to a language.

The problem is that the use of an ActionListener added to the Picker is not correct for this purpose, because it's triggered by both "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons.

I need to execute some code (to change the language) only and only if the user press "Ok", because executing that code if the user press "Cancel" should be considered an unexpected behavior and a bug (from the point of view of the user).

So my question is how to use correctly the Picker in this use case.

Comment: Action listener should only happen on OK or if the user clicks the entry. If it happens when cancel is pressed or when a user presses outside of the picker UI to dismiss the UI it's a bug. In that case we need **exact** details of where this bug occurs including full OS version number as it differs a lot between OS versions.

Comment: I have fixed it in git so that the ActionEvent is no longer fired when the user presses cancel.  https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/c794e702ee73a6176440adf03c3aafdd425ad0f1  Will be available in next server update Friday.

Answer (score 2):

From the CN1 documentation, one way to do this would be :

```
String [] list = {"one" , "two" , "three"};
Picker picker = new Picker ();
picker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
picker.setStrings(list);
picker.setSelectedString("test");

picker.addActionListener(l -> System.out.println(picker.getSelectedString()));
```

Oddly, and as Francesco has pointed out in a prior moment, when you run the application IN THE SIMULATOR, and press the Cancel-Button inside the picker, it prints out the selected string. Same when you press the OK-Button. (Is this intended?)

On installed devices, the results seem to be mixed, as to on some devices the cancel operation does not incur in any action.

Comment: Thank you, but I need a consistent behaviour on real devices, because I need to execute some code (to change the language) only and only if the user press "Ok", because executing that code if the user press "Cancel" should be considered an unexpected behavior and a bug (from the point of view of the user). Any workaround or trick (even using something different from a Picker component but useful for this use case)?

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this to avoid triggering another listener on the string (I was using a Property with a change listener) if Cancel was pressed, and I did this by checking the current picker string against the previous selected string to see if it changed. I only updated the field or local variable (Property in my case) if the value changed. Modifying the previous answer's code:

```
...
private String currentSelection;
...

String [] list = {"one" , "two" , "three"};
Picker picker = new Picker ();
picker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
picker.setStrings(list);
picker.setSelectedString("test");

picker.addActionListener(l -> {
   if (!picker.getSelectedString.equals(currentSelection) {
      currentSelection = picker.getSelectedString;
      System.out.println(currentSelection);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you James, however see the Steve Hannah comment to my question, it should be the real solution of the problem.